# How to indexing lat lon on PostgreSql to make it faster

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am using `PostgreSQL 8.4` and have table with lat lon. This 2 field(lat,lon) are character varying and total record inside are more than 100K.

I already create index like this below:-

```
  CREATE INDEX latlon
  ON lyr_gtpencemaran
  USING btree
  (lon, lat);
```

when I query like

```
Select * from mytable
```

it's take about `3085ms`.

Can anybody have a idea how to make it faster query?

Thanks you on advance for any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: You are using an asterisk wildcard in your `SELECT`, which renders your index mute. Try querying with using your column names directly: `SELECT lat, long FROM mytable`. Remember that you have to create an `index` in accordance to *how* you query your data. Simply creating an index is on half the story and does not guarantee it will be used.

Comment: Thanks you mr.incohnito and Timusan for your reply. I will try any possibility to solve this by yours suggestions.

Comment: After try many time and add fields on query like "SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 from mytable order by field1" it's reduce query time to 500ms.

Comment: You select all data, a sequential scan is by far the fastest solution to get all data. Without a WHERE condition or an ORDER BY, no index can speedup your query.

Comment: @Timusan: The wildcard in the SELECT clause has nothing to do with whether PostgreSQL will use an index.

Comment: @Mike The asterisk itself will indeed not kill your index, but the expension of it (select all columns) in most cases will, since people usually don't have indexes on a combination of everything. Indexes are many times tailored to more specific usage (certain columns). Thus it is by convention considered bad practise and ... in OP's case has everything to do with his index not being used if his table has more then just the lat/long columns.

Comment: @Timusan: *"in OP's case has everything to do with his index not being used"* The OP's index isn't used because he has no WHERE clause, not because he's selecting every column. You can select a single, indexed column without a WHERE clause, and PostgreSQL will still do a sequential scan.

Comment: @Mike, I guess my explanation of the wildcard issue was a bit poorly addressed in the context, so it seems. You are correct, the missing `WHERE` clause is indeed the main issue in OP's case. Apologies for stirring possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL won't use an index if you select every row from a table. Let's do a test.

```
-- A primary key constraint creates an underlying index.
create temp table test (
  n integer primary key
);

insert into test 
select generate_series(1, 100000);

analyze test;
```

Select just a *few* rows, and PostgreSQL will use an index.

```
explain analyze
select n 
from test
where n between 500 and 530;

"Index Only Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.29..8.95 rows=33 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.023 rows=31 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: ((n >= 500) AND (n <= 530))"
"  Heap Fetches: 31"
"Total runtime: 0.045 ms"
```

You won't get an index-only scan on 8.4, because that feature was introduced later. But you'll still get an index scan.

Select *all* the rows, and PostgreSQL will use a sequential scan.

```
explain analyze
select n 
from test;
```

```
"Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..1443.00 rows=100000 width=4) (actual time=0.025..16.794 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 23.835 ms"
```

If you want PostgreSQL to use an index, select fewer rows.